Replicating Measure Line Tool Output programatically for rotated/oriented rectangles
What I have
I have some oriented rectangles/polygons that represent boats in a geoJSON file. The coordinates of the points are in EPSG:4326. Example here:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "class_index": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.472774175475876, 50.584330403288234 ], [ -2.472803344007858, 50.584359220029107 ], [ -2.472904479118332, 50.584317949919956 ], [ -2.472875310586487, 50.584289133179084 ], [ -2.472774175475876, 50.584330403288234 ] ] ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "class_index": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.472920047644104, 50.584445290591809 ], [ -2.47286213925238, 50.58449154487554 ], [ -2.472895653768265, 50.584508460405416 ], [ -2.472953562159988, 50.5844622061216 ], [ -2.472920047644104, 50.584445290591809 ] ] ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "class_index": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.457114818462265, 50.575098684249994 ], [ -2.457055118029587, 50.57516427463721 ], [ -2.457100906794937, 50.575181083460222 ], [ -2.457160607227753, 50.575115493072921 ], [ -2.457114818462265, 50.575098684249994 ] ] ] } }
    ]
    }

....
The Goal
I want to get the lengths and widths of the boats/rotated polygons, in meters. Using the Measure Line widget in the UI (which is using EPSG:7030 in ellipsoidal mode) seems to give me the results I'd expect, but I want to replicate this programmatically, adding the values to an output geoJSON.
What I've tried
def calculate_length(geojson_path):
    # Load GeoJSON file
    with open(geojson_path, 'r') as f:
        geojson_data = json.load(f)

    # Define source (EPSG:4326) and destination (EPSG:3857) CRS
    crs_source = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326')
    crs_dest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857')

    # Create coordinate transform
    transform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crs_source, crs_dest, QgsProject.instance())

    # Iterate over features and calculate length
    for feature in geojson_data['features']:
        geom_coords = feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0]  # Extract the first set of coordinates
        points = [QgsPointXY(coord[0], coord[1]) for coord in geom_coords]  # Convert to QgsPointXY
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points])  # Create QgsGeometry from points
        geom.transform(transform)  # Transform geometry to destination CRS

        # Calculate length by iterating over segments
        length_meters = 0.0
        prev_point = points[0]
        for point in points[1:]:
            segment_length = prev_point.distance(point)
            length_meters += segment_length
            prev_point = point

        # Add length to properties
        feature['properties']['length_meters'] = length_meters

I know I need to transform between source (EPSG:4326) and destination (EPSG:3857) CRSs because 4326 is not in meters, however I'm surprised that there isn't a simple tool in PyQGIS/QGIS that can do this for me (please tell me I'm wrong).
Converting (using 'Save As') the layer to EPSG:3857 (and 4936 which I've also tried), always gives me dimensions that I know are too large. I've tried looking for EPSG:7030 to match the tool but it's not there.
Please can anyone help? Do I need to split the boxes into vertices, or use a skeleton tool to get a centreline?
I'm going round in circles with it a bit.
Expected Output for the input examples above:
Polygon 1 should be around 8.5m x 3.7m
Polygon 2 should be around 6.5m x 3m
Polygon 3 should be around 8.3m x 3.6
EDIT 12/05/2024: Added clarification that the rectangles are rotated/oriented and provided expected output (based on using the GUI Measure Tool Widget). I think I might need to rotate them in code and then measure them with the bounds.length tools but current attempts have failed with odd output.

Don't use 3857 for any sort of analysis

If you look in the manual you will find there is a built in method to handle this (I'm pretty sure it is how the measure tool works). So you need something like:
d = QgsDistanceArea()

d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
length_meters = 0.0
prev_point = points[0]
for point in points[1:]:
        segment_length = d.measureLine(prev_point, point)
        length_meters += segment_length
        prev_point = point

or probably easier:
 length_metres = d.measureLength(feature['geometry'])

to save all the overhead of keeping score.
If you need to change to kilometres or miles etc then there are methods for that too.
Update
With the following code I get:
Width 3.813568623013943 Height 8.507675349988489
Width 6.579868285886863 Height 3.028974581481936
Width 8.433273235274555 Height 3.7438862814342455

which seem like reasonable sizes for boats, and matches what I get in QGis with the measure tool.
import json                                                                                                             
from qgis.core import QgsDistanceArea,  QgsPointXY                                                                      
                                                                                                                        
d = QgsDistanceArea()                                                                                                   
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
def measureLine(c1, c2):                                                                                                
    p1 = QgsPointXY(c1[0], c1[1])                                                                                       
    p2 = QgsPointXY(c2[0], c2[1])                                                                                       
    return d.measureLine(p1, p2)                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
input = """{                                                                                                            
    "type": "FeatureCollection",                                                                                        
    "crs": {"type": "name", "properties":                                                                               
        {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},                                                                     
    "features": [                                                                                                       
    {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"class_index": "0"},                                                             
    "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates":                                                                      
        [[[-2.472774175475876, 50.584330403288234],                                                                     
        [-2.472803344007858, 50.584359220029107],                                                                       
        [-2.472904479118332, 50.584317949919956],                                                                       
        [-2.472875310586487, 50.584289133179084],                                                                       
        [-2.472774175475876, 50.584330403288234]]]}},                                                                   
    {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"class_index": "0"},                                                             
        "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates":                                                                  
            [[[-2.472920047644104, 50.584445290591809],                                                                 
            [-2.47286213925238, 50.58449154487554],                                                                     
            [-2.472895653768265, 50.584508460405416],                                                                   
            [-2.472953562159988, 50.5844622061216],                                                                     
            [-2.472920047644104, 50.584445290591809]]]}},                                                               
                 {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"class_index": "0"},                                                
                 "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates":                                                         
                     [[[-2.457114818462265, 50.575098684249994],                                                        
                     [-2.457055118029587, 50.57516427463721],                                                           
                     [-2.457100906794937, 50.575181083460222],                                                          
                     [-2.457160607227753, 50.575115493072921],                                                          
                     [-2.457114818462265, 50.575098684249994]]]}}                                                       
                    ]                                                                                                   
            }"""                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
features = json.loads(input)['features']                                                                                
for feature in features:                                                                                                
    coords = feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0]                                                                      
    d1 = measureLine(coords[0], coords[1])                                                                              
    d2 = measureLine(coords[1], coords[2])                                                                              
    print(f"Width {d1} Height {d2}")     


Thanks :) How does that compare to measureLine() and measureLineProjected()? I don't seem to be able to get the results I'm expecting and chatGPT is sending me in circles a bit now too.

can you add an example line for us to look at

I should've added that the polygons (rectangles) are oriented bounding boxes. I think what I'm getting is the length of a longitudionally (word?) aligned bounding box that contains the rotated rectangle, but I'm looking for the length (and width) of the rectangle itself. The above is an example of the input.

correction, the input polygons are oriented/rotated rectangles.

Wow, Thankyou! I had just gotten to a solution using a different approach (calculating the UTM zone and then using the correct EPSG for the UTM). My numbers are slightly different as you'd expect, but a negligible difference:
Polygon 1 - Length: 8.513477701385767 metres, Width: 3.8121279078383523 metres
Polygon 2 - Length: 6.585698258524101 metres, Width: 3.026786989162625 metres.
Your code will run a lot faster I expect. Thankyou!
